# setMethod and package Matrix

Tags: r, r-s4

I am creating an S4 class that uses package Matrix and then using setMethod to redefine "sin" for my class

```
> library(Matrix)
> setClass("foo",slots=list(z="Matrix"))
> setMethod("sin",signature(x="foo"),function(x){return(cos(x@z))})
[1] "sin"
```

however, even before I get started using my class I encounter a problem

```
> y<-Matrix(c(1,2,1,2),2,2)
> sin(y)
2 x 2 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.8414710 0.8414710
[2,] 0.9092974 0.9092974
> sin(y)
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : object '.Generic' not found
```

Why does the second use of sin(y) fail ? This is my first attempt at programming with S4 classes. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

At some level this looks like a bug that should be reported to the [R-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-devel) mailing list. But `sin()` is a member of the `Math` 'group generic' (see `?GroupGenericFunctions`), and one could implement

```
setMethod("Math", "foo", function(x) callGeneric(x@z))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just posted an alternative solution in a thread with a similar question 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37566785/2116352 without having to overload the whole generic group.
tl;dr: Overload the individual function within a package and load the package.